# current image not deleting from array

Tags: iphone, arrays, uiimageview, long-press

I stored multiple images in database. And i fetched the images using SQLite and added these to array. When i click the button it displays the array of images under scrollview. In scrollview when i click particular image it goes to center of the screen. Center of the screen images having another imageview. When i delete particular image from array, the current image is not deleting.

code:

SQLiteManager:

Table name: SimpleTbl

```
  id    sm     descrip        photo
    1      sm1    ok            BLOB(size:2345)

    2      sm2    ok1            BLOB(size:3245)

    3      sm3    ok2            BLOB(size:4535)
```

.h file:

```
@interface Mysof : NSObject{
    NSInteger sofId;
    NSString *sof;
    NSString *rating;
    UIImage *photo;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *sofa;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger sofaId;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *rating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *photo;
```

.m file:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getMylists{
    NSMutableArray *sArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
        }

      ;


        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM SimpleTbl";       


        NSLog(@"sql is %s", sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
        }

        //
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            Mysof *Mylist = [[Mysof alloc]init];
            Mylist.sofId = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
            Mylist.sof = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            Mylist.rating = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];
            const char *raw = sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 3);
            int rawLen = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 3);
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:raw length:rawLen];
            Mylist.photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            [sArray addObject:Mylist];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
    @finally {
        return sArray;
    }

}
```

Then viewcontroller i display the fetching image to imageview via button click:

```
-(void)click:(id)sender{

for (int i = 0; i<[self.arraysofs count]; i++ ) {
            NSLog(@"index %d",i);



          //  imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 500, 72, 72)];

            imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

            Width = Width + 20+(i*74);

            [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

            [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(arraysofsClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [imgView1 setImage:((Mysof *)[self.arraysofs objectAtIndex:i]).photo forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];

          //  [myScroll addSubview:imgView1];



        }

}
```

It displays the center of the screen:

```
-(void)arraysofsClicked:(id)sender{


 NSLog(@"button %d is clicked.", [sender tag]-1);



    mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];

    [mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

     [mmageView setImage:((Mysof *) [self.arraysofs objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]).photo];

    [self.view addSubview:mmageView];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *dblongpress=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dblongPress:)];

    [mmageView addGestureRecognizer:dblongpress];

}
```

Long press for deleting images from center of the screen:

```
-(void)dblongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender{

   //  NSLog(@"button %d is clicked.", [send tag]-1);

   // [mmageView setImage:((Mysof *) [self.sofas objectAtIndex:[send tag]-1]).photo];

    [mmageView removeFromSuperview];

  }
```

If two images on the center of the screen, when i click first images the second is removing.

Answer (score 0):

The imageview you are seeing after deleting is the older one which you added earlier. This is because every time you press the button, it calls -(void)arraysofsClicked, and a new instance of the imageview is added there.

Solution is:

put this in viewDidLoad

```
mnageView = nil;
```

& Change this method

```
-(void)arraysofsClicked:(id)sender{

// chcek is mnageView is initialized before or not
if(mmageView == nil) {

    mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];

    [mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


    [self.view addSubview:mmageView];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *dblongpress=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dblongPress:)];

    [mmageView addGestureRecognizer:dblongpress];

}


// change image here
[mmageView setImage:((Mysof *) [self.arraysofs objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]).photo];

}
```

declare the mnageView globally in case you are not doing so. but from your code it seems you are declaring it globally.